# Firebug Lite, unaxpected token %

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm trying to launch **Firebug Lite** using the [Bookmarklet](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable):

```
javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

If I run it in the address bar nothing happens, if I run it within the javascript console (both MSIE10 and Google Chrome) say:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

I've tried all the available channels of Firebug Lite with the same result.
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to use Firebug Lite in those modern browsers, when they both come with reasonably good dev tools? The only times I've needed to use Firebug Lite have been with really old browsers like IE7 that don't have their own built-in dev tools.

Comment: Because the select element tool of the debug tool of IE10 doesn't select lot of the elements of my page.

Comment: That's surprising. IE10's dev tools aren't as good as some others, that's for sure, but I've never had an issue with them doing basic stuff like that. (btw, IE11's dev tools are *much* better than IE10's; worth making the upgrade for).

Comment: I can't, I'm on a corporate PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `%20` with a space?

Comment: I've already tried it and by the way when you save the bookmarklet in the bookmarks it's automatically replaced.

Comment: So, you get a SyntaxError "Unexpected token %" even when you get rid of all `%` signs? That sounds absurd - is it coming from inside the Firebug lite library or something?